# On what relies the limit for maximum eSims on my device?

Tags: esim

I have a Pixel6 and it supports 1 eSim.

Since eSims are just software, **what are the limiting factors** to not have basically unlimited eSims on a smartphone?

Where is it coming from?:

- The lawmaker?
- The telcos?
- The phone manufacturers?
- The phone operating system manufacturer?

Comment: Any or all of the above.  To manage real production and price point, everything is designed to have limits, thats life.  What are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eSIM are not pure software. For security reasons the storage is a hardware component similar to the old SIM cards, just way smaller and AFAIK today integrated into the central SoC.

Also your statement "Pixel6 and it supports 1 eSim" is not correct. you can only have one eSIM active at a time but you can have multiple eSIM profiles installed and easily switch between them (usually you can have up to eight eSIM profiles installed, they are often called "lines").

The reason why you have only one eSIM is because the phone is designed to work as a dual-SIM phone: one physical SIM and one eSIM can be active.

Each active SIM requires the phone to search for the operator network and then connect to it and keep the connection. So when two SIM "cards" are active the whole radio system of your phone is shared between two providers. This means increased radio traffic and the necessity to manage things like hand-over and so on two times in parallel. This means it costs battery and it can come to conflicts where both connections want to use the radio system and the antennas at the same time.

Increasing the number of active SIM cards would increase those situations so each connection would suffer.